# Cannot get webapps to work after upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: unity, webapps

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04. But I cannot use WebApps. In fact there is no sign of them anywhere. Firefox and Chromium are not prompting for integration.

I tried re-installing both browsers/webapps plugin of each, but no luck. Out of curiosity, I tried to install unity-webapps-preview through terminal, `apt-get` reported that this operation is going to need `127mb`. After installation, restarting session, nothing.

I re-ran the unity-webapp-preview in terminal and SURPRISINGLY it again asked me that this operation is going to need `58mb`. After Installation, nothing.

Firefox is showing the unity-webapp plugin in Extensions but in Preferences there is noting like *Unity settings* or options for exceptions in *General* tab (as I seen in some threads).

Chromium is not even showing the plugin in *Extensions* nor in the settings. Really need help. I know there is a reported bug but it is mostly about the complains that the webapps are not working as they should but in my case they don't seem to exist.

EDIT: The out put of `gsettings list-recursively | grep webapp` is:

```
com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains @as [] com.canonical.unity.webapps dontask-domains @as [] com.canonical.unity.webapps index-update-time 43200 com.canonical.unity.webapps integration-allowed true com.canonical.unity.webapps preauthorized-domains ['amazon.ca', 'amazon.cn', 'amazon.com', 'amazon.co.uk', 'amazon.de', 'amazon.es', 'amazon.fr', 'amazon.it', 'www.amazon.ca', 'www.amazon.cn', 'www.amazon.com', 'www.amazon.co.uk', 'www.amazon.de', 'www.amazon.es', 'www.amazon.fr', 'www.amazon.it', 'one.ubuntu.com']
```

Comment: What do you mean by *re-ran the `unity-webapps-preview`*? Please edit your question to include the output of `gsettings list-recursively | grep webapp`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You seem to be using two different accounts. Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for them to be merged. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep webapps` as well? Thanks :)

Comment: downgraded to 12.04 from 12.10? upgraded to 13.04 from 12.10? Typo. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version for Ubuntu (stable) is 13.10 and not 12.10, do a clean install to that version and post your feedback, remember to do a backup of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I use Trusty, so I cant test this solution, but I found this PPA for webapp integration for Quantal(12.10) https://launchpad.net/~webapps/+archive/preview

Visit this link, and select on "View package details" and find and download integration packages for your browser, and then install "unity-webapps-2.0-0quantal1" (or you may do this first before downloading integration packages for your browser)

Hope this works.